# Issue while installing selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pip

My system configurations are:

OS: Windows10
Python installed with Anaconda.

When I try to install "Selenium"  with pip using command `pip install selenium`. It gives following error:

```
D:\>pip install selenium
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl
module in Python is not available.

Collecting selenium



    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
    us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/

    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
    us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
    us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL becau
    se the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
    us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL becau
    se the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, stat
    us=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL becau
    se the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/selenium/
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/selenium/: There was a problem con
    firming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
     retries exceeded with url: /simple/selenium/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect
     to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from
    versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium
    WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl
    module in Python is not available.

    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming
    the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retrie
    s exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS UR
    L because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Are you running this from the anaconda command prompt with activated environment?

Answer (score 0):

You’d try from [Anaconda Prompt](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#open-anaconda-prompt).

You will see (base), now upgrade pip.
Example:

Python code:

```
(base) C:\Users\Tom>cd ..
(base) C:\Users>cd ..
(base) C:\>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in g:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)
(base) C:\>pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
# Try install
(base) C:\>pip install selenium
```

This takes a longer time, but will also install or upgrade SSL libraries that Anaconda uses internally.

Python code:

```
(base) C:\>conda update condo
......
pyopenssl-19.1.0     | 47 KB     | #################################### | 100%
openssl-1.1.1f       | 4.7 MB    | #################################### | 100%
```

[Source](https://therefor.life/support/how-to-solve-an-issue-pip-installing-selenium-warning-tls-ssl/)

Answer (score -1):

Try below command it worked for me-

```
easy_install selenium
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).